# NodeJS MVC asynchronous request

Tags: node.js

I'm getting undefined data from controller to model request in NodeJS.

My Model:

```
const db = require('../util/database');

module.exports = class Property {
    constructor(pID) {

    }

    getPropertyByID(pID) {
        let property = {};
        db.execute('SELECT * From Properties Where PropertyID = ' + pID)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res[0][0];
                if(data){
                    //console.log(data); This shows DATA if I remove the comment
                    property = data;
                }
                return property;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Then, in my controller I tried to use the Model method.

```
exports.sendDataID = (req, res, next) => {
   const propID = req.params.propID;
   if(propID) {
      const property = new Property();
      const data = property.getPropertyByID(propID);
      console.log(data);
   }
};
```

The console.log(data) is returning undefined. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Comment: `db.execute` returns a Promise that your code does not return. Use `return db.execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use async and await function to return a promise result.

```
async getPropertyByID(pID) {
    let property = {};
    try{
        var res = await db.execute('SELECT * From Properties Where PropertyID = ' + pID)
        property = res[0][0]; //not sure what res variable is
        return data
    }catch(error){
        return error
    }
}
```

and for use this function you only need to do this:

```
const propID = req.params.propID;
if(propID) {
    const property = new Property();
    const data = await property.getPropertyByID(propID);
    console.log(data);
}
```

I recomend you to read about promises functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise

Comment: How can I have the try/catch to valid any issue in the SQL query?

Comment: I updated the getPropertyByID function, I am not completly sure if that works it depends what are you doing inside db.excecute.